# How to fix OAUTH 2 redirect uri error "400 Oauth2 policy keeping apps secure."

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, redirect-uri

I got

[image: this error]

please help me

[image]

I changed redirect_uri on google develop console

http://localhost:8000/api/google-callback

and

https://localhost:8000/api/google-callback

both got same error

Comment: It works fine on my local machine but on ec2 not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please post a picture of what you have in Google could console.  It says you have not added it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

is telling you that you are using HTTP when you should be using HTTPS

Your application is sending from `http://localhost:8000/api/google-callback` which is not considered safe for use with authorization.   you need to configure your application to run https so that it will send from https.

[Use secure redirect URIs and JavaScript origins](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/production-readiness/policy-compliance#use-secure-redirect-uris-javascript-origins)

[image]

Comment: I modified to use the https protocol and the same symptoms appear.

Comment: Is your application set to production?   set it back to test.

Comment: it's test mode. I think my url has a problem, but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Well from what i can see you havent added it under JavaScript origin yet. You must add exactly what the message says http:// localhost:8000/api/google-callback  looks like you have added everything but.